# Present UISplitViewPopover programmatically

Tags: ios, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I was wondering if there was a sort of simple way to (when the device is in the correct Portrait orientation), to programmatically display the `RootViewController` in the `UIPopoverController` of the `UISplitViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `UIBarButtonItem` that the split view gave you in it's delegate callback. You can use that one:

```
[barItem.target performSelector:barItem.action withObject:barItem];
```

Its a hack, but works. Please file a request at http://bugreport.apple.com for a better solution.

Comment: That gives me a `-[UIBarButtonItem toggleMasterInPopover:]: unrecognized selector` -- am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No but I did a typo. Corrected now.